# Bash remove until null

Tags: bash, null, pipe, delimiter

I'm trying to remove all characters up to and including the first null character in an input stream.

I've tried this, which:

1. uses echo to create an input with two lines. each line has a 0 in the middle.
2. use translate to convert 0s to nulls. now we have two lines which both have null in the middle.
3. use cut (the attempted solution)
4. use od to view the output

```bash
$ echo $'ab012\nab012' | tr '0' '\0' | cut -f2- -d '' | od -An -t uC
  49  50  10  49  50  10
```

The output from od reads as: 1, 2, \n, 1, 2, \n.

This solution is incorrect since cut applied this operation to each line, instead of just from the beginning. The correct output should instead be: 1, 2, \n, a, b, \0, 1, 2, \n.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Utilities that process text files generally can't deal with null characters, because that's the string terminator in C.

Comment: If you have null characters in the file, it's a binary file, not a text file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have GNU `sed`:

```
echo $'ab012\nab012' | tr '0' '\0' | sed -z '1d' | od -tx1
```

`-z` option of `sed` is a GNU extension.

Or, a pure `bash` way, as stated in the comments:

```
echo $'ab012\nab012' | tr '0' '\0' | { read -r -d ''; cat; } | od -tx1
```

When used with the option `-d ''`, bash builtin command `read` will terminate a line when it reads a NUL character.

Comment: `{ IFS= read -rd'';cat;} <input_with_null >output_truncated_from_up_to_null`

Comment: @LéaGris Thanks for the trick, but I don't think `IFS=` is necessary for this case.

Comment: `printf 'ab\00012\nab\00012\n' | tail -zn-2 | od -tx1`